# Authenticating a webrequest by adding Cookies throws error

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication

In my website I am using forms authentication.And I want to make a webrequest for this purpose i am taking help of **cookieContainer**.My code is this

```
 string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
    Cookie authenticationCookie = new Cookie(
        FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,
        cookie.Value,
        cookie.Path,
       HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority);
    req.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    req.CookieContainer.Add(authenticationCookie);
    WebResponse res = req.GetResponse();
```

but this code throws an error "**The 'Domain'='localhost:300' part of the cookie is invalid.**".Thus i found error is coming from this line of code

```
Cookie authenticationCookie = new Cookie(
    FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,
    cookie.Value,
    cookie.Path,
   HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority);
```

The url of the site is localhost:300. I am unable to find any solution for this.can any one tell me what went wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try excluding the port number from the domain property you are passing to the Cookie constructor:

```
Cookie authenticationCookie = new Cookie(
    FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,
    cookie.Value,
    cookie.Path,
    HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host
);
```

or set the cookie as an HTTP header directly without using a cookie container:

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
req.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Cookie] = string.Format("{0}={1}", cookie.Name, cookie.Value);
WebResponse res = req.GetResponse();
```

Comment: I don't know why ,but when code execution reaches this line
"WebResponse res = req.GetResponse();" it is going back to first line (HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);)as it is in a loop.and finaly throws an error "The request was aborted: The operation has timed out."

Comment: I have no idea why this might be happening. Maybe you have multiple threads. Hard to tell from the code you have shown. Maybe the problem is on the server side. Now that you are successfully authenticated, there must be some other problem on the server. You could activate the network trace and see exactly what's getting sent over the wire by following those steps: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty48b824.aspx. Or simply use a tool like Fiddler to see what happens under the covers.